# Batch: How to scroll through files to read to a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd

I'm trying to have it scroll through a directory and present a new variable when the user replies "N". I have it all figured out except how to go to the next variable.

```
cd "C:\Test"
for /r %%F in (*) do SET Show=%%~NF
echo %Show%
echo.
SET /P Continue=Continue?(Y/N)
if /I "%Continue%" EQU "y" goto :Run
if /I "%Continue%" EQU "n" goto :Start
```

Comment: Can you explain what `scroll through` mean? And also what exactly do you want? It's unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to scroll the directory and prompt the user the file name and have them choose to choose it or continue, then bellow should help you.

Firstly, we can use `dir /b /a:d` to display only directories (folders) in the the current directory. By using a code block `(` & `)` we can put batch script inside the for loop. For your sake, we can use the `CHOICE` command to prompt to continue the loop or to save current folder to string and do something with it.

**ScrollTreeWithPrompt.bat:**

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Rem | Configuration
Set "MainDir=C:\Test"

Rem | Get Each Project Folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir "!MainDir!\" /b /a:d') do (

    Cls
    Echo Current Folder: %%A
    echo(
    CHOICE /M "Continue?"

    Rem | Check for "N" - If so Set String & goto
    IF "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="2" (
        Set "Choice=%%A"
        GOTO Run
    )
)

Rem | No Further Results
Cls
Echo Warning: No further folders found.

pause>NUL
goto :EOF

:Run
Cls
echo Currently selected: !MainDir!\!Choice!

pause>NUL
goto :EOF
```

---

I have left a few `Rem` comments in the script to help you along. For any more help on the commands, type the following into a command prompt:

- `choice /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need:

```bat
For /R "C:\Test" %%A In (*) Do (Choice /M "%%~nA"
    If Not ErrorLevel 2 (Set "Show=%%~nA" & GoTo Run))
Exit /B
:Run
Echo Running against %Show%
Pause
```

Alternatively, should you wish to return to the loop after running against the file name, then use `Call` instead of `GoTo`:

```bat
For /R "C:\Test" %%A In (*) Do (Choice /M "%%~nA"
    If Not ErrorLevel 2 Call :Run "%%~nA")
Exit /B
:Run
Set "Show=%~1"
Echo Running against %Show%
Pause
```